# Is my work considered legal in Russia?

Tags: money, study, work

This is my first question in this place. Apologies, if I break any posting rules, I'll read the comments and edit the question as required to make it more proper.

Currently I work in country A as a contractor for an organisation based in country B for past one year (as a remote software developer). I recently got accepted to a university master program in Russia and planning to join it soon. I would like to work during study period of two years to support myself financially. Currently, my only source of income is from this contract job and if it gets terminated I'll lose my source of income.

My employer wants to keep me and is happy to provide me small work for the next two years and pay the price so I it will benefit both parties. Will it be legal if I continue to work remotely while in Russia? My income now and in future too will be transferred to my home country (country A) bank only. I will be okay to pay the conversion rate price when I transfer this money from the Country A bank to future bank in Russia and keep paying my taxes in country A to support myself.

I am not planning to inform this to the authorities if it is a legal path, if not I will terminate my employment.

Thanks

Comment: Questions about longer stays for work and study belong in Expatriates Stack exchange.